# I want to change the url for mobile user to m.mysite.com with same mobile view look in browser

Tags: redirect, mobile

I need my site www.mySITE.com to open as m.mySITE.com on mobile devices. It has SSL set up also. Please share the code and file name as I do not have any coding knowledge.I want to display the same theme as it is looks like now, only need to change the url.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please specify which version of Magento you are using?

What is your end goal with this mobile version of the site if the theme is going to be the same?

You can setup JS redirects based on browser-type. I would start with adding a new store-view under your current store. This is where you can specify the new domain to use (replacing WWW with SUBDOMAIN). Keep in mind you'll need to ensure your cookie settings include this subdomain for both store-views and you'll want to test and make sure that the shopping cart is able to carry products between these views as well.